# EF Core table naming for entities exposed as collection navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm on EF Core 7.

Given the following models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public List<Issue> Issues { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Issue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

and my DbContext:

```
internal class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=testapp;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;");
    }
```

After a `dotnet ef migrations add`, the `Up()` method looks like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
  migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Projects",
    columns: table => new {
      Id = table.Column < int > (type: "integer", nullable: false)
        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn)
    },
    constraints: table => {
      table.PrimaryKey("PK_Projects", x => x.Id);
    });

  migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Issue",
    columns: table => new {
      Id = table.Column < int > (type: "integer", nullable: false)
        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
        ProjectId = table.Column < int > (type: "integer", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table => {
      table.PrimaryKey("PK_Issue", x => x.Id);
      table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Issue_Projects_ProjectId",
        column: x => x.ProjectId,
        principalTable: "Projects",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

  migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Issue_ProjectId",
    table: "Issue",
    column: "ProjectId");
}
```

My issue is that `Project` gets pluralized to `Projects`, but `Issue` does not.

Using the name of the `DbSet<T>` property as the table name is among the default conventions, and I'm okay with that.

`Issue`, on the other hand, does not appear as a `DbSet` property and stays singular, leading to an inconsistency in the naming convention. To be honest I'm okay with either singular or plural table names, it's just a matter of preference. What I'm not okay with are glaring inconsistencies.

Of course I could use either `[Table("Issues")]` or `modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>.ToTable("Issues")`, or even just expose `Issue` as `DbSet<Issue> Issues { get; set; }` on my context, but EF Core's behavior when naming a table whose entity is exposed as a collection seems odd to me.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to get EF to pluralize `Issue` without forcing it manually?

I looked for this extensively, but while I think even the official documentation states that entities that are exposed as `DbSet`s will use the name of the property, I couldn't find anything about what the rules are when naming tables for entities exposed as a collection navigation property from other entities.

Comment: EF Core is not pluralising the table name. You have defined the table name (by convention) via the `DbSet` name. You could have called that property `AnyThing` and EF Core would use that name for the table. But you can opt-out of that convention (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#built-in-conventions / https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions/issues/15#issuecomment-1374547142) Or replace it with something else.

Comment: I for one dislike relying on convention and simply `[Table("name")]` attribute every entity, as well as keys & FKs. No surprises. (Slight pain that EF Core doesn't support composite keys by attribute yet, but I generally avoid those where possible)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks. I had seen that comment on GH and saw that removing the convention did work as expected, I was wondering whether I was doing something wrong and there was a way to get EF to behave consistently. For someone new it's kind of surprising. I will go with this and Steve's suggestion.

Comment: @StevePy thank you very much. This validates the opinion I was forming that it's better to be explicit about everything than relying on conventions, despite what most tutorials and guides show.

Reading the docs, it appears that EF Core 7 now supports composite primary keys through the new `PrimaryKeyAttribute`, it looks like `[PrimaryKey(nameof(OneProp), nameof(AnotherProp))]`.

And thanks in general, your other answers to EF-related questions I read were alwasy super helpful.